# UITableViewCell with dynamic content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have UITableView with dynamical cells content.

Each cell can have different content, images, text, for example. 
I can `t know in advance what content will be placed in the cell and correspondingly can not I create variables in advance.

Cells may have say 0-5 frames for images.

If I create (alloc) need me frames for images in LayoutSubviews, all work but, when I reload table, all frames is allocated( because in LayoutSubviews is recreate all my variables.

How I can create or what mechanism for create cell with dynamics contents!

```
 for (int i=0;i<[_cellAttachments count];i++) {

        if ([[[_cellAttachments objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"type" ] isEqualToString:@"images"]) {

            UIView *attachmentsView = [[UIView alloc] init];
            attachmentsView.frame = CGRectMake(10, postHeight+10, 300, 48);
            [self.contentView addSubview:attachmentsView];

// some another code
```

I know if create variable like @property for attachmentsView all ok in LayoutSubviews, but my cellAttachments array can have many object with different type for fill cells...

Number of different types of cells in my case more than 50 combinations, that not idea for create more that 50 custom cell's

Comment: Did you set the delegate and dataSource = self?

Comment: Please, read basics how to use UItableView

Comment: yep, cell created is normally, all cell with a different content I assign different cell identifcators, if in array of data I assign first object all ok. I added some example code to question

Answer (score 0):

So based on your data you would be deciding which cell comes on which row right ? Its fairly easy to establish this and performing this logic in layoutSubview's is not quite right.

Create  different custom tableCell classes for each type of cell. And give them an unique cell identifier each.

Assuming your using storyboard's in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method dequeue each cell and return the right one based on your data.

Here's an example .

```
 static NSString*cellTypeA = @"CellTypeA";
 static NSString*CellTypeB = @"CellTypeB"";

    CellTypeA* cellObjectA  = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: cellTypeA];

    CellTypeB* cellObjectB = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: cellTypeB];

if (someLogic)
{
   return cellObjectA
}
else
{
  return cellObjectB
}
```

Comment: Yes,if my cellTypeA has 1 attachment image for example, and cellTypeB has 2 attachment images, that you answer right. But if attachment is different has type and different count of attachments images, I cannot create subclass of uitableview cell for each different variants of attachments

Comment: Number of different types of cells in my case more than 50 combinations, that not idea for create more that 50 custom cell's

Comment: But if attachments increase you need to change the container for the image's . For example you could place a scrollView on the contentView of the cell and have images placed horizontally across the scrollView and you can swipe through attachments. Or you could look at UICollectionView , it offers this kind of support in a much easier way.

Comment: you mean to use instead of a table collections, or in each cell paste Collections?

Comment: I would recommend you to use UICollectionView instead of UITableView to get the desired functionality.